# Laravel could not autoload a model from within Acme Directory?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

in my Laravel app I have created Acme\fooDir directory inside app directory

i am trying to call a model -"barModel"- from within the fooDir

```
 //app/Acme/fooDir/test.php 
 $barM = new barModel;
```

but i am getting this error

```
        Class 'Acme\fooDir\barModel' not found
```

here is my app structure

```
  app
  -app/Acme
  --app/Acme/fooDir
  ---app/Acme/fooDir/test.php (this is the file that could load the barModel)
  -app/models
  --app/model/barModel.php (this is the model i am trying to use)
```

I have added autoload in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": 
    { 
        "Acme": "app/"           
    }
```

and
I have ran the command

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

and

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

but the problem not solved and i am still getting the same error

```
    Class 'Acme\fooDir\barModel' not found
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When using `namespace` all your classes are called within that `namespace`.

If you want to use `barModel` in `Acme/fooDir/test.php` your will need to use `use barModel;` just after your `namespace` row.

```
<?php
namespace Acme\fooDir;

use barModel;

class test {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1, Have you namespaced your classes ie,

```
<?php namespace Acme\FooDir;

class Test ...
```

2, Are you using use in your class

```
<?php namespace Acme\FooDir;

use \BarModel

class Test ...
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick for you.

```
 $barM = new \barModel;
```

[PHP namespaces and importing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)